# Getting output of AsyncTask in other class

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-alertdialog

I am learning android development I have to check whether a file is present on server.

I am using following code

```
public class CheckReportExists extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>{

    Boolean fileExists = false;

    public CheckReportExists() {

    }

    public Boolean CheckReportExists1(String download_url){
        execute(download_url);
        return fileExists;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //display progress dialog.

    }
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
            HttpURLConnection con =  (HttpURLConnection) new URL(params[0]).openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
            int response = con.getResponseCode();
            if(response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                fileExists = true;
            }
        } catch(Exception e){

        }
        return fileExists;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        // dismiss progress dialog and update ui
        //super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

To call this I am using following code

```
     CheckReportExists cre = new CheckReportExists();
     Boolean fileExists = cre.CheckReportExists1(download_url);
     if(fileExists) {
          builder.setPositiveButton("Download Report", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                 new DownloadTask(Results.this, download_url);
          }
          });
      }else{
            builder.setPositiveButton("Report not ready yet", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
             });
      }
```

But this code is not working time I get `AlertDialog` with "Report not ready yet" button even when the file is present on the server.

Thank you.

Comment: `CheckReportExists1()` will always return a false value because it won't wait until the `AsyncTask` finishes its work

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
 CheckReportExists cre = new CheckReportExists() {
     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // RIGHT HERE is where you can add your code to handle the result
     }
 };
 // CheckReportExists1 is no longer a good name because it's not
 // returning a value.  It just starts the process.
 cre.CheckReportExists1(download_url);
```

Comment: This is an [anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) BTW

Answer (score 0):

`CheckReportExists1()` will always return a `false` value; and that's because it runs in UI thread and it won't wait until the `AsyncTask` finishes its background work. So it will always return the its initial assigned value which is `false`

To solve this you can create a listener interface with a callback method that takes a `Boolean` that indicates whether the file exists or not. And trigger this callback whenever you actually make sure that the file does exist or not after your background work is over.

So change your code with:

The listener interface:

```
interface OutputListener {
    void checkFile(Boolean exists);
}
```

AsyncTask:

```
public class CheckReportExists extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>{

    Boolean fileExists = false;
    OutputListener listener;

    public CheckReportExists() {

    }

    public void CheckReportExists1(String download_url, OutputListener outputListener){
        execute(download_url);
        listener = outputListener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //display progress dialog.

    }
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
            HttpURLConnection con =  (HttpURLConnection) new URL(params[0]).openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
            int response = con.getResponseCode();
            if(response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                fileExists = true;
            }
        } catch(Exception e){

        }
        return fileExists;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if (listener != null)
            listener.checkFile(result);

        // dismiss progress dialog and update ui
        //super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

AsyncTask usage:

```
CheckReportExists cre = new CheckReportExists();
cre.CheckReportExists1(download_url, new OutputListener() {
            @Override
            public void checkFile(Boolean exists) {
                if(fileExists) {
                    builder.setPositiveButton("Download Report", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                             new DownloadTask(Results.this, download_url);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    builder.setPositiveButton("Report not ready yet", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            }
                     });
                }

            }
        });
```